# Open drawing's function with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to know if it's possible to open the drawing's function (insert menu then drawing)only in script apps?
I can't find any information on the subject on the internet and I'd like to set this up because I use Google Sheets on a tablet and I don't want to use the "PC view".
Thank you in advance for your help.